# Better way of handling a .weights.h5 content in a response

Tags: python, python-requests, tf.keras

My client code is supposed to get the contents of a .weights.h5 file from the server in it's response.

```
response=requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        weights_file_contents=response.content
```

After getting it I want to load it into a model with `model.load_weights(file_path)`. However since this method only accepts file path I'm saving this to a temporary file and deleting it after use.

```
file_path = "temp.weights.h5"
with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(weights_file_contents)
model.load_weights(file_path)
os.remove(file_path)
```

Is it possible to pass this file contents through python to that method without creating any external file at all?